# Angular project with kendo ui doesn't build on linux server

Tags: angular, npm, kendo-ui

I'm building an angular 10 app, everything works fine on my local windows dev instance. But when I run the build pipeline on a linux server the ng build process fails with this error output:

`Property 'readonly' is missing in type '{ mode: "row"; multiple: false; drag: false; enabled: true; }' but required in type 'SelectableSettings'.

55     this.settings = {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-treelist/dist/es2015/selection/selectable-settings.d.ts:47:5
47     readonly: boolean;
~~~~~~~~`

On both machines I have the same npm, angluar cli, node versions. I try to clean the node_modules and the npm cache before the ng build command on the linux machine but the dist folder it's not generated.

I update the kendo tree list to the last version but it also doesn't work.

Seems like an issue with es2015 package version but I don't know how solve it.

I try to update npm, node and ng and set it to the same version on server and dev machine. I try to clean npm cache, I try to remove node_modules folder.

Comment: Have you ever executed `ng build` on your dev machine? Im assuming you are using `ng serve` on your dev machine which does not run any optimizations. Some errors only occur on production builds.

Comment: if it's about es2015 package versions, you might want to check the tsconfig.json on your angular app, and see the compilerOptions and play with it.

for lib: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib check this info, for target https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target this.